# My vb.net code just replaces specified string by contents of rich text box. But I want to replace it with alignment also

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, richtextbox, office-interop

I need to replace a specific string in a MS Word with text of Rich Text Box. I have achieved my that using the following code.

```
objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="Comments1", _
                                ReplaceWith:=COMMENTS.Text, _
Replace:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

But, What my actual requirement is.. I want to replace it by exact text of rich text box with alignment.

For example :

1. Kindly add the title to you article,
2. Kindly add the abstract to your article

the above text is the content of rich text box.

But, in my word document it replaced as

1. Kindly add the title to you article, 2. Kindly add the abstract to your article

Have you noticed that ? After the 1st point I have hit enter key and then only I have give 2nd point.

But, resultant text are concatenated with the 1st point.

So, what to do to get exact text with alignment of rich text box in my word document.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall something about Rich Text Box using `vbLf` for line feeds instead of `vbCrLf`, which I believe is what MS Word would expect to be used for a line feed.  You might try something like this (air code):

```
objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="Comments1", _
                            ReplaceWith:=COMMENTS.Text.Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf), _
Replace:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

Comment: Yeah.. Just now I tried. It's works.. Thank you  MJH :)